# UnboundLocalError with Python on ArcGis

Tags: python, arcgis

I'm working on ArcMap and I have this python code :

```
import arcpy, sys

feature = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)


def nearRoutine():
    #calculate the distances using the current dataset
    arcpy.Near_analysis(feature, feature)

    #iterate through any features which are within the distance
    cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(feature, '"NEAR_DIST" < 500')
    row1 = cur.next()
    while row1:

        #this point is within the distance of its neighbor, so delete it
        cur.deleteRow(row1)

        #now re-run this routine on the new dataset
        del row1, cur
        nearRoutine

#call the recursive routine. It will get progressively faster to run as it will loop through fewer points each time
nearRoutine()
```

My error message : UnboundLocalError: local variable 'row1' referenced before assignment

I don't understand because my variable is clearly define...

Someone have an issue ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for providing a sample of code along with your question. I am curious what you hoped would happen in this code: `while row1: ... ; del row1 ...`.

Comment: Be sure that my variables are erased before restarting my order nearRoutine

Comment: I see. Calling `nearRoutine` recursively doesn't so much *restart* the function as create a new instance of it. Local variables are unique to each instance of the function; the "row1" in the inner function frame is wholly unrelated to the "row1" in the outer function frame, so the `del` is unnecessary. And, as you have discovered, bad for other reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You delete `row1` and then continue to iterate through requiring (checking) it!

I'm not sure you really need to use `del` on your variable `row1` or `cur` where you have it.  You are removing those variables, not their contents in your data structure.

Comment: I redefined my two variable I delete (row1 and cur) and it's work Thanks

Comment: Glad I was able to help.  Be sure to `accept` this answer by clicking the checkmark next to its score.